# How do you connect a .SQL Database to Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, sql, jupyter-notebook, sqlalchemy

As you need to connect a database for using SQL and I don´t want to use pg Admin due to lack of visualization, I prefer to use Jupyter Notebook or Visual Studio Code.
With this said, I want to connect it to one of them, I´m trying with Jupyter.

I have been following a guide where I have connected my DataBase and I know it is connected due to the Terminal:

```
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [5432]:
Username [postgres]:
Contraseña para usuario postgres:
psql (16.0)
ADVERTENCIA: El código de página de la consola (850) difiere del código
            de página de Windows (1252).
            Los caracteres de 8 bits pueden funcionar incorrectamente.
            Vea la página de referencia de psql «Notes for Windows users»
            para obtener más detalles.
Digite «help» para obtener ayuda.

postgres=#
```

Once this is done, I´m trying to connect it but it oesn´t work. What I have done is the following.

```
pip install ipython-sql
%load_ext sql
```

The next step will be to connect to a PostgreSQL database. You will connect to the database that you created - DataCamp_Courses. This is the name of my Database.
`pip install psycopg2`
But when I enter the direction:
`%sql postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/DataCamp_Courses`
I throws an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) 
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)

Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
               postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
               or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
```

How do I solve this? Is it easier to connect it on VS Code or Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: I think it should be `%%sql ...`? Have you reviewed the examples [here](https://pypi.org/project/ipython-sql/)?

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to connect via Jupyter Notebook by importing mysql.connector

```
import os
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import socket
import mysql.connector
```

Then login with your database details (I am using root@localhost for demo) and create your Database, the cursor object is used to communicate with the DB

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(

host="localhost",
user="root",
password="myPassword"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE testDB")
```

You can check your sql connection for your databases then to see if it worked:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
user="root",
password="myPassword"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")

for x in mycursor:
 print(x)
```

I see now that the OP is using PostgreSQL. The Jupyter Notebook approach is very similar for DB connection

```
import library psycopyg2
import psycopg2

import library pandas
import pandas as pd

import library sqlio
import pandas.io.sql as sqlio

create database connection variable 
conn = psycopg2.connect(user="user", password="myPassword", 
host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", database="testDB")
```

Comment: My apologies, I misread.

Comment: The point is that I´m using PostgreSQL, in that case I use the second block of code? @RMC

Comment: @ManuelVeiga yes import psycopy2 to connect to postgreSQL in Jupyter notebook